# Why is Z3 unable to prove `unsat` for this query, whereas cvc5 succeeds?

Tags: z3

I have a (relatively) simple query attached below

```
(set-logic AUFLIRA)
(set-option :produce-models true)

(declare-sort Loc 0)
(declare-sort HeapChunk 0)
(declare-sort HeapIndex 0)

(declare-fun makeHeapChunk (Loc Real) HeapChunk)
(declare-fun valid ((Array HeapIndex HeapChunk)) Bool)

(declare-const empty (Array HeapIndex HeapChunk))

(assert (
    forall (
        (heap (Array HeapIndex HeapChunk))
        (i1 HeapIndex) 
        (i2 HeapIndex) 
        (l1 Loc) 
        (l2 Loc) 
        (own_val1 Real) 
        (own_val2 Real)
    )

    (=> 
        (and
            (valid heap)
            (= (select heap i1) (makeHeapChunk l1 own_val1)) 
            (= (select heap i2) (makeHeapChunk l2 own_val2)) 
            (> (+ own_val1 own_val2) 1)
            (not (= i1 i2))
        )

        (not (= l1 l2))
    )
))



(declare-const index0 HeapIndex)
(declare-const index1 HeapIndex)
(assert (not (= index0 index1)))

(declare-const l1 Loc)

(declare-const heap0 (Array HeapIndex HeapChunk))
(assert (valid heap0))

(assert (= heap0 (store empty index0 (makeHeapChunk l1 0.6))))

(declare-const heap1 (Array HeapIndex HeapChunk))
(assert (valid heap1))
(assert (= heap1 (store heap0 index1 (makeHeapChunk l1 0.5))))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
(exit)
```

It should return `unsat` because `heap1` contains two elements which violate the constraints in the big assertion (essentially because `0.6 + 0.5 > 1` and `valid(heap1)`). Giving this example to cvc5 returns `unsat` which is the expected outcome, but z3 returns `unknown`. I want to understand why, and what I can do to help z3 figure this out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When quantifiers are involved, you're at the mercy of heuristics. Looks like z3 is failing to recognize some pattern that cvc4/5 is handling better. Report it at https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues and they might be able to fix it, or recommend you a work-around.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try reporting it to their Git.